# nomenclature of citric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: citric acid]

I named Citric acid : "3-hydroxypentan-1,3,5-trioic acid" 
but when I searched , I found that the right name is "3-carboxy-3-hydroxypentane-1,5-dioic acid"

Can anyone explain to me why my nomenclature is wrong?

Comment: Note that, although the name “3-carboxy-3-hydroxypentane-1,5-dioic acid” is unambiguous and describes the correct structure, it is not in accordance with current IUPAC recommendations. The preferred IUPAC name is “2-hydroxypropane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid”. Furthermore, the name “citric acid” is also retained for use in general nomenclature, but no substitution is recommended; however, the formation of salts and esters is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must find the longest chain, which incidentally does not contain one of the carboxylic acid groups. The longest chain is 5 carbons long (hence pentane), there are 2 carboxylic acid groups on this chain, one on each end (hence pentane-1,5-dioc acid), there is a hydroxy group on the third carbon in the chain (hence 3-hydroxypentane-1,5-dioc acid), and finally there is also a carboxylic acid group on the third carbon (hence the full systematic IUPAC name: 3-carboxy-3-hydroxypentane-1,5-dioic acid).

Answer (score 1):

The "-oic" ending means to convert the carbon into a COOH group, not that there's an additional COOH group added to that carbon.

Look at your main chain. You have five carbons, of which carbons 1 and 5 are fully oxidized, hence "pentane-1,5-dioic acid". If the "COOH" group was counted as an independent entity adding an additional carbon, then it would be a *three* carbon chain, to which was added two COOH groups.

That's why it can't be a 3-oic acid - that would imply that the third carbon of main chain has been oxidized to a COOH group (which is preposterous), not that there's a COOH group that's been added. Instead, the COOH group (carboxy) has been appended to the three position, and the molecule is named accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would name it as an 1,3,5-trioic acid then the carbon atom of the 3-carboxy group had to be part of the of carbon skeleton from which the name of the acid derives, namely 3-methylpentane, not pentane.

So the name is 3-carboxy-3-hydroxypentane-1,5-dioic acid, or, named as carboxylic acid, 2-hydroxy-1,2,3-propanetricarboxylic acid.

Answer (score -1):

**2-hydroxypropane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid** is the correct name. For tricarboxylic acids we are finding longest carbon chain with **excluding** carboxyl groups. Then we are naming it with all fuctional groups but without carboxyl groups. At the end position carboxyl groups and say tricarboxylic acids.